# If new data else stop insert over and over

Tags: javascript, ajax

To keep it simple, I'm just wanting to know how I'd go about and if else statement against my ajax to print new data out once if it finds it and not the same data over and over again. Amd how can I possibly store the last id as a variable to reuse it when searching for more new records?

Someone mentioned to me also I could save the new notification idea as a return so when the ajax restarts it uses this to find the next new set of results.

Has anybody got any ideas how to achieve these?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){

var time = new Date().getTime();
  var notification_id="<?php echo $notification_id['notification_id'] ;?>"

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id+"&time="+time ,   
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(response){
if(response.num){
$("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id).prepend('<div  id="notif_actual_text-'+response['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><a href="'+response['notification_id']+'">'+response['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+response['notification_time']+'</div></nr>');

 $("#mes").html(''+ response.num + '');
}
}
});
},20000);

</script>
```

Comment: your question is too vague.  What defines "new data" ?  What "last id" ?

Comment: notification_id is what I send to the server side, response.notification_id is the response. I would like the new notification_id to be only inserted once into the div and then it start as search against that new notification_id instead of the same data it originally checked.
Or I've also being told I could do an if new notification_id insert else..nothing. then send the last new notification_id to be searched on the next interval.

Comment: Are the notification_id and the response.notification_id expected to match?

Comment: No the notification_id is the last id in the table.. sends to server side to look for any new data.. if it has a new one it outputs.. only if there is a new one it searches against the same last id and prints the new data out over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to store the last id, you could use:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

Then when you want to get it again you'll should use:

```
var lastId = window.localStorage.getItem ('key');
```

And regarding the duplicates issue, well, you should have a internal storage in order to handle the recieved data. May be an array can help as storage, also you can also store this array in local storage.

Once you handle this data storage, you could apply something like this to verify that your data has no duplicates:

```
var dataHandler = function (response){
   var isDuplicate = false, storedData = window.localStorage.getItem ('key');

   for (var i = 0; i < storedData.length; i++) {
     if(storedData[i].indexOf(response) > -1){
        isDuplicate = true;
     }
   }
   if(!isDuplicate){
     storedData.push(response);
   }
}; 

var printer = function(response){
   if(response.num){
      $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id).prepend('<div  id="notif_actual_text-'+response['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><a href="'+response['notification_id']+'">'+response['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+response['notification_time']+'</div></nr>');

      $("#mes").html(''+ response.num + '');
    }
};
```

UPDATE

```
var notification_id = window.localStorage.getItem ('lastId'); 
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id+"&time="+time ,   
    dataType:"json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
    if(response){
    dataHandler(response);
    if(response.num){
       window.localStorage.setItem('lastId', response.num);
    }
    });
    },20000);
```

Comment: Whats the key and value?

Comment: Ok... you can call at dataHandler function in the success callback for your ajax call.
'key' is suppose to be the name for your global variable, value is the value assigned for this key variable. So, if you want to store the request id then your key must be 'requestId' or something like that.